# Perl captured digits from string are always 1

Tags: perl, digits

On my journey to start learning `perl`...

I encountered this funny behaviour, and can't seem to wrap my head around it.

```
my $username = "bandit0";
my $command = "";

sub next_command {
    my ($user) = @_;
    my $num = $user =~ /(\d+)/;
    print "$num\n";
    if ($num == 0){
        return "cat readme";
    }
    elsif ($num == 1){
        return "ls";
    }
}

sub next_level {
    my ($user) = @_;
    my $num = $user =~ /(\d+)/;
    $user =~ s/\d//g;
    $user = $user . $num++;
    return $user;
}

$command = next_command($username);
print $command . "\n";
$username = next_level($username);
$command = next_command($username);
print $command . "\n";
```

After running this small perl program, I would expect something like this:

```
0
cat readme
1
ls
```

However I get something like this...

```
1
ls
1
ls
```

I don't understand why, at first string `bandit0` the `$num` will be `1` instead of `0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The match operator in scalar context evaluates to a boolean that indicates whether the match succeeded or not.

```
my $success = $user =~ /(\d+)/;
```

The match operator in list context returns the captured strings (or `1` if there are no captures) on success and an empty list on error.

```
my ($num) = $user =~ /(\d+)/;
```

You used the former, but you want the latter. That gives you the following (after a few other small fixes):

```
sub next_level {
    my ($user) = @_;
    my ($num) = $user =~ /(\d+)\z/;
    $user =~ s/\d+\z//g;
    $user .= ++$num;
    return $user;
}
```

But that approach is complicated and inefficient. Simpler solution:

```
sub next_level {
    my ($user) = @_;
    $user =~ s/(\d+)\z/ $1 + 1 /e;
    return $user;
}
```

Comment: Impressive, using a substitution I think? Could you maybe elaborate on the simpler version. Because to me it is not that obvious what it does.

Comment: Replaces trailing digits (`\d+\z`) with the sum of `$1` (the captured string (the digits)) and `1`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this and see if it works. if it helps, I will explain everything. I cannot test this myself right now.

```
use strict;   # always use strict
use warnings; # always use warnings

my $username = "bandit0"; #try bandit1 to ensure it prints 1 and ls instead
my $command = "";

sub next_command {
    my ($user) = @_;
    my ($num) = $user =~ /(\d+)/;
    print "$num\n";
    if ($num == 0){
       return "cat readme";
    }

    elsif ($num == 1){
        return "ls";
    }
}

sub next_level {
    my ($user) = @_;
    my ($num) = $user =~ /(\d+)/;
    $user =~ s/\d//g;
    $user = $user . ++$num;
     return $user;
}

$command = next_command($username);
print $command . "\n";
$username = next_level($username);
$command = next_command($username);
print $command . "\n";
```

Comment: I had to do  `$num += 1;` and `$user = $user . $num;` for some reason. But yes the parenthesis was what I missed.

Comment: This should work fine without having to do the `$num += 1; ...` but ok, if you managed then it is fine, will delete the answer.

Comment: The `num++` would give me back `bandit00` instead of `bandit1`, I really don;t know why, as I said. Just started learning perl ;)

Comment: the problem with `$num++` is that it returns the value of `$num` *before* the increment. `$num + 1` is ok if you don't need it later, otherwise use `++$num`